# Tag merge request: [minecraft-spigot] to [minecraft-bukkit]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, minecraft, tag-merging

Could we merge [minecraft-spigot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-spigot) to [minecraft-bukkit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit) as most of the Spigot (a fork of Bukkit) questions are also applicable on Bukkit and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea. Even if most of the questions for Spigot also apply to Bukkit as you claim, they're still separate programs that work different in some respects, so knowing how to do something in one of them might not apply to the other. This would be similar to merging C and C++ on Stack Overflow, or merging Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 on Super User. It's not because they're related to each other that they're the same.

---

After doing some more research, it turns out that Spigot and Bukkit are not the same. Bukkit is an API that allows mods to do extra stuff on your server. then there's CraftBukkit, which is the Minecraft server software with Bukkit baked in. Then there's Spigot, which is CraftBukkit with extra improvements.

Based on this summary, my original comparisons may be a bit wrong, but my conclusion isn't: they're not similar enough to warrant merging the tags. Spigot is a modded minecraft server, while Bukkit is an API to install mods into a minecraft server.

Comment: Actually, Spigot is a direct fork of Bukkit and Bukkit is maintained nowadays by the Spigot team. Spigot is just a bunch of patches to (Craft)Bukkit improving performance and adding new features, not two completely different but really similar programs.

Comment: @Tassu see my edit.

Comment: Bukkit is an API for coding plugins (questions about coding would go to StackOverflow) and CraftBukkit is the official Bukkit implementation with the pieces that load the plugins, handles commands, sends events to the plugins, and basically hooks the vanilla server and the api together. Spigot is an extension to *both* Bukkit and CraftBukkit. Both of the tags are used for questions related to the server configuration, using plugins, uploading worlds, etc. The question nature of both tags is pretty much the same.

Comment: We shouldn't look for what Spigot and Bukkit have in common or not. It's about how we use the tags. If the questions about one of these also fit into the other one a merge may be useful. If not, leave it.